# Could it be possible to make css selector affect other elements in the page without javascript?

Tags: css, focus, css-selectors

For example, I want to make two textboxes have the same style when either is focused:

```
<div class="divTxt">
    <input type="text" id="a" class="a" />
    <input type="text" id="b" class="b" />
</div>
```

and the css would be:

```
.a:focus 
{
    background-color:Blue;
}
.b:focus 
{
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

What I need is make a's background-color:Yellow when b is focused and vice versa.
any possibilities? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's doable w/o Javascript -- and what's wrong with doing it in Javascript, anyway?

Comment: It's for the browsers with disabled javascript. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [General Sibling Selector(~)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) if the input boxes are next to each other.

Something like:

```
.a:focus {    background-color:Blue;}
.a:focus~.b {    background-color:Blue;}
.b:focus {    background-color:Yellow;}
.b:focus~.a {    background-color:Yellow;}
```

Note: Completely untested and a stab in the dark at best!

Comment: Good point +1. A pity this is not well implemented in older browsers.

Comment: Not to mention buggy in IE7, the linked article mentions it's compatability issues.

Comment: thanks, but this is not used by older browsers... And there are still a large number of people who use the old ones.

Comment: change .a:focus~b to .a:focus~.b... this is not working when b is focused. Thanks a lot anyways. =)

Comment: @Jronny, with those constraints I think you could be stuck. If a solution can be found, they will certainly get my vote!

Answer (score 0):

If they've got javascript disabled, they probably won't notice text box styles.

Comment: well, it's their fault they disabled javascript anyways. They would not notice the beauty of my creation. *evil laugh*

Answer (score -2):

```
.chk1:focus{
   background-color:Blue;
}
.chk2:focus{
   background-color:Yellow;
}
```

text feilds

```
<input class=chk1 type=text id="a">
<input class=chk2 type=text id="b">
```

This one will work fine with FireFox but might have issues with IE6 
See [CSS Issue Focus For IE6](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/focus_pseudo_class/)

If you want this to work with IE, you might want to use javascript!!

Hope this helps

RDJ